# SSRS Insert Space Between Numeric and Alpha Characters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am having an issue where a field is stored in our database as '##ABC' with no space between the number and letters. The number can be anything from 1-100 and the letters can be any combination, so no consistency of beginning letter or numeric length.

I am trying to find a way to insert a space between the number and letters.

For example, '1DRM' would transform to '1 DRM'
             '35PLT' would transform to '35 PLT'

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions like the one below (assuming your pattern is digits-characters)

```
= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace( Fields!txt.Value, "(\d)(\D)", "$1 $2")
```

Comment: This seems to work great. Although looking at it, I am unable to explain what its doing. Can you shed some light as to what the symbology means for the 2nd and third parameters of the function? Just curious. Thanks!

Comment: The function uses regular expression replacement. The second parameter is what to match \d a number and \D a not numeric character. The third parameter defines the replacement pattern. A nice site about regular expressions https://regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no built in function to do this.

Fortunately, Visual Studio lets you create functions to help with things like this.

You can add Visual BASIC custom code by going to the Report Properties and going to the Custom Code tab.

You would just need to write some code to go through some text input character by character. If it finds a number and a letter in the next character, add a space.

Here's what I wrote in a few minutes that seems to work:

```
Function SpaceNumberLetter(ByVal Text1 AS String) AS String

DIM F AS INTEGER

IF LEN(Text1) < 2 THEN GOTO EndFunction

F = 1 

CheckCharacter:

IF ASC(MID(Text1, F, 1)) >= 48 AND ASC(MID(Text1, F, 1)) <=57 AND ASC(MID(Text1, F + 1, 1)) >= 65 AND ASC(MID(Text1, F + 1, 1)) <=90 THEN Text1 = LEFT(Text1, F) + " " + MID(Text1, F+1, LEN(Text1))

F = F + 1

IF F < LEN(Text1) THEN GOTO CheckCharacter

EndFunction:

SpaceNumberLetter = Text1 

End Function
```

Then you call the function from your text box expression:

```
=CODE.SpaceNumberLetter("56EF78GH12AB34CD")
```

Result: [image]

I used text to test but you'd use your field.